# SonarQube A NullPointerException could be thrown; Conn is nullable here

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, findbugs

I have created the connection from HttpsURLConnection to set all the parameters to it. In the end finally block i am disconnecting it as showin below. But the SonarQube build is not passing. Showing as bug while disconnecting the connection.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, proxnet);    
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)urlStr.openConnection(proxy);
con.set...();

finally{
   conn.disconnect();
}
```

SonarQube addressing the Bug inside finally block with NullPointerException.

keeping a NotNull check enough to the conn object? Or is anything to be done here apart from a not-null check? I am trying in different ways.

A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "conn" is nullable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me highlight the location of a possible exception:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, proxnet);    
HttpsURLConnection conn;
conn = (HttpsURLConnection)urlStr.openConnection(proxy) /* EXCEPTION! variable is not assigned */;
con.set...();

finally{
   conn.disconnect();
}
```

`conn` remains set to its initial value (`null`). The safe route is to add a null check in the finally block:

```
finally {
  if (conn != null) conn.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: I think we should do this null check as you said.

Comment: @Mdhar9e If you don't want a NullPointerException, you have to check for nulls :)

Answer (score 1):

when you put initiation on `(HttpsURLConnection)urlStr.openConnection(proxy);` it is possible to have an exception and don't initiate conn also finally will be run at any situation so sonar predicate a nullPointerException. maybe you need check `conn != null` before calling `conn.disconnect();` in finally.